# Apps installed via Flatpak on Pop OS unable to upload, download, import, export, or save files

Tags: permissions, download, pop-os, flatpak

I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (a flavor of Ubuntu), all updates available in the Pop Shop have been installed. Apps installed via flatpak appear to have a permissions issue.

For example--

- Brave: can't import bookmarks
- Calibre: Add books > select file gets message "calibre, version 6.9.0 ERROR: Cannot add books: You do not have permission to read any of the selected files."
- Newsflash: Can't import file containing feeds, freezes when trying to import file
- Element: Can't attach files
- Zoom: Can't attach files in chat
- KeePassXC: Can't add attachments, freezes when tried
- Signal: Can't upload or download attachments, crashes after asking where to save the file.

I've installed Flatseal, but changing its settings has not helped (possibly because it too is a flatpak app). I also reinstalled flatpak. Running the apps from terminal doesn't help. Rebooting has not helped, nor has repairing flatpak.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you launch a Flatpak app from the CLI passing the `--filesystem=home` flag? E.g. `flatpak run com.brave.Browser --filesystem=home`.

Comment: Thanks. Same problem. I tried Signal so `flatpak run org.signal.Signal --filesystem=home
`. Pressed the down arrow next to a photo to save it, was prompted to pick a location and then the app crashed.

Comment: Did you get any messages in the console?

Comment: Yep! Just put it on pastebin (please LMK if there's a better way to share messages or code that are longer than what we can post in the comments). Thanks!

https://pastebin.com/f7DN06W4

Comment: Re Calibre error. There is a section in the documentation faq that may be helpful: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#i-am-getting-a-permission-denied-error

I am not sure it is wise to assume these are related problems and related to a system wide permissions problem. (Which seems unlikely in a fresh Pop install unless there were problems during installation.) I assume you have made sure your system is up to date by running `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` (if you find anything to upgrade).

Comment: Have you looked at the permissions of the files that won't upload/import? And at the permissions of the `flatpak` apps in question? Run `ls -Al` in their respective directories. (In Pop `ll` is equivalent to `ls -Al`. I usually use `ll`.)

Comment: Of the apps in question, Zoom is the only one I have installed on my Pop 22.04 system. I installed it from a `.deb` package downloaded here: https://zoom.us/download. If you would like to try this, run `flatpak uninstall us.zoom.Zoom` to uninstall the flatpak (you can re-install later if you like). I have never used attachments in chat so no guarantees.

Download the "zoom_amd64.deb" file to your Downloads directory. I also downloaded the signing key but never had o manually use it. To install it run `cd ~/Downloads` then `sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb` (don't forget the leading `./`).

Comment: So I had a Zoom tonight. To test it out I uninstalled Zoom debian package version 5.9, and I installed a fresh deb package version 5.12.9. I tried attaching a file to the chat, a jpeg, and it worked fine. I mention this in case that feature is important and you want to try this package as an alternative to flatpak.

Comment: Thanks @Steve 

- Calibre troubleshooting didn't apply.
- Fresh install done by System76
- All software is up to date
- Sticking with Signal as an example, permissions are `drwxr-xr-x`.
- Thanks for the Zoom tip. Wasn't critical, so I didn't bother installing a different package. I did that with Thunderbird though, when its flatpak install wouldn't import my messages, and it worked fine.

Comment: One more thing. When you show permissions for Signal I assume you are showing either `home/[username]/.local/share/flatpak/app/org.signal.Signal` or `home/[username]/.var/app/org.signal.Signal` (honestly, I do know what role each of these play).

Check the ownership as well as permissions to see how that compares to the ownership of the files you have been trying to attach; eg, on my system `ll ~/.var/app/org.kde.okular` will show `drwxr-xr-x 6 steve steve 4096 Jul 10 10:07 org.kde.okular/`

Answer (score 0):

You should grab the Flatseal app from the Pop Shop. It will allow you to enable all of the Flatpak permission with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by deleting and re-installing all the Flatpak apps.